# Scrapy can't follow url with commas without encoding it

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Can I force scrapy to request an URL including commas without encoding it into `%2C`? The site (phorum) I want to crawl does not accept encoded URLs and redirecting me into root.

So, for example, I have site to parse: `example.phorum.com/read.php?12,8`

The url is being encoded into: example.phorum.com/read.php?12%2C8=

But when try to request this url, every time, I'm redirected into page with list of topics:

```
example.phorum.com/list.php?12
```

In those example URLs 12 is category number, 8 is topic number.

I tried to disable redirecting by disabling RedirectMiddleware:

```
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': None,
    }
```

and in spider:

```
handle_httpstatus_list = [302, 403]
```

Moreover I tried to rewrite this URL and request it by sub parser:

```
    Rules = [Rule(RegexLinkExtractor(allow=[r'(.*%2C.*)']), follow=True, callback='prepare_url')]
    def prepare_url(self, response):
        url = response.url
        url = re.sub(r'%2C', ',', url)
        if "=" in url[-1]:
            url = url[:-1]
        yield Request(urllib.unquote(url), callback = self.parse_site)
```

Where parse_site is target parser, which still calls using encoded URL.

Thanks in advance for any feedback

Answer (score 2):

You can try `canonicalize=False`. Example iPython session:

```
In [1]: import scrapy
In [2]: from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.regex import RegexLinkExtractor   
In [3]: hr = scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(url="http://example.phorum.com", body="""<a href="http://example.phorum.com/list.php?1,2">link</a>""")
In [4]: lx = RegexLinkExtractor(canonicalize=False)
In [5]: lx.extract_links(hr)
Out[5]: [Link(url='http://example.phorum.com/list.php?1,2', text=u'link', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```